# Unable to save changes in Azure DevOps pipeline task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

After updating an inline script in a task in Azure DevOps pipeline Task Group, I'm getting an error when saving my changes:
"Task Group cannot be saved because it references service connections that cannot be found, or that you don't have permission to access: 'xxxx' ".

Since I am a member of the Contributor role, this role has permission to edit the task group and I am also a Contributor in the service connection 'xxxx'. What other permissions do I need to be able to save my task changes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Since I am a member of the Contributor role, this role has permission to edit the task group and I am also a Contributor in the service connection 'xxxx'. What other permissions do I need to be able to save my task changes?

In my project, I have the **contributor role**, but I'm also getting the same result as you.

[image]

To resolve the issue, I assigned the **Build Administrators** role to the user.

**Role Assignment:**

[image]

After assigning the role to the user, I'm able to edit the `Task Group` settings as follows.

[image]

In order to edit the `pipeline`, to add an `inline script` you need to make sure to have necessary permission for your `contributor` role.

To verify the permission, you can follow the below steps.

Go to your **Project** > **Pipelines** > Select the **All** tab, and then select the more actions menu then **Manage security** and check **Allow edit build pipeline** option is enabled.

[image]

Reference: [Set pipeline permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @VenkatV. A couple questions, why do we need to assign the Build Administrator role to the user? And why give the permission to Edit build pipeline when the Task Group I am having trouble with is in the Release pipeline (which in my case, the Contributor role already has)?

Comment: Hi @cenko: **Contributors**: Has permissions to contribute fully to the project code base and work item tracking. The main permissions they don't have are permissions that manage or administer resources.

**Build Administrators**: Has permissions to administer build resources and build permissions for the project. Members can manage test environments, create test runs, and manage builds. Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups) for more details